Identifying symmetries of rank 2 tensors
Let's say I have a material with permittivity tensor: $$ \epsilon_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon_{xx} & \epsilon_{xy} & 0 \\
\epsilon_{xy} & \epsilon_{yy} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \epsilon_{zz} \end{pmatrix} $$
and another mateirial with permittivity and permeability tensors:
$$ \epsilon_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \epsilon & iG & 0 \\
-iG & \epsilon & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \epsilon_{zz} \end{pmatrix} , \mu_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \mu & iB & 0 \\
-iB & \mu & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \mu_{zz} \end{pmatrix}$$
How do I see that these 2 materials have space-inversion symmetry?
I know for a vector, eg: the magnetic field $B \propto k \times E$, you can see that $B$ has space-inversion symmetry since $k \rightarrow -k$ and $E \rightarrow -E$, so $B \rightarrow B$. But I'm having trouble generalizing this to rank-2 tensors.
Thanks!
